# Prevent duplicating Bootstrap dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to create [dropdown menus](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns).

It's working fine, but I have the exact same menu on every row of a table. Adding the menu for every row in the table seems a big waste to me. Also, it prevents me from assigning a unique ID to menu items.

Is anyone familiar with a way to use the Bootstrap drop down to assign a single menu wherever it's needed, in response to the item being clicked? Rather than redefining the menu everywhere it might be needed?

Comment: Have you tried using AJAX to fetch the information?

Comment: @JorgePeña: That wouldn't provide any advantage because I already know the exact commands that I want in the menu. Perhaps you didn't understand the question?

Comment: you want to reuse dropdown-menu right?

Comment: @this.girish: Yes, sort of like the way another JavaScript menu that I've used does it. You define the menu once, and then when it needs to be displayed, you pop it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this might help you,in order to achieve what you wanted

```js
//save the selector so you don't have to do the lookup everytime
$dropdown = $("#contextMenu");

$(".linktodisplay").click(function () {
    //get row ID
    var id = $(this).closest("tr").children().first().html();

    //move dropdown menu
    $(this).after($dropdown);

  
    //show dropdown
    $(this).dropdown();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>test 1</th>
            <th>test 2</th>
            <th>test 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Harry</td>
            <td>sahil</td>
            <td class="dropdown"> <a class="btn btn-default linktodisplay" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    Click me
                </a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>sahil</td>
            <td>nimish</td>
            <td class="dropdown"> <a class="btn btn-default linktodisplay" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    click me 2
                </a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>anu</td>
            <td>potter</td>
            <td class="dropdown"> <a class="btn btn-default linktodisplay" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    click me 3
                </a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="itemlink1">Item1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="itemlink2">Item2</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```